# cannot find the index.html in reactcreateapp

Tags: html, reactjs, create-react-app

I am a static page app with react and I want to link a stylesheet to the app through the index page but I cant find its location.

There is an index.js page on the app which selects the root id like this `document.querySelector('#root')` by I cant locate the html file where the root id is coming from. Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

oops,
I found it in the public folder